# Trouble with dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to write a program in python to display inventory and number of each item in inventory, but having difficulty pulling values from dict...
Using Python 3.5 on Win10, through default Python editor
From chapter 5 sample problem of "Automate the Boring Things with Python"

```
i={'color':'red','gold':3}
def bP(n):
    inv=''
    for v in n:
        print (str(n)+':'+str(n[v])) #Problem is first print not displaying value 
bP(i)
```

Comment: What output are you trying to get? Please provide your expected output

Comment: `print (str(v)+':'+str(n[v]))` (note it's `str(v)`, not `str(n)`)

Comment: "Automate the Boring Things with Python" is ""Automate the Boring Things with Python with more boring things",  they should talk about `dict.items(),` or `dict.values()` instead of looping like this

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ You are the bomb, that fixed it.

Comment: @PDouglas Cheers, glad to help.

Comment: @idjaw I wanted to list the objects in the dictionary and their values, no matter the length of the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following example:

```
d={'color':'red','gold':3}

for key,value in d.items():
    print(key,value)
```

output:

```
gold 3
color red
```

`d.items()` outputs a key,value pair.

Also,

```
for item in d.values():
    print(item)
```

output:

```
3
red
```

But,

```
for key in d.keys():
    print(key)
```

output:

```
gold
color
```

**However** just doing this gives the same result as above,

```
for key in d:
    print(key)
```

output:

```
gold
color
```

So in your case,

```
for v in n:
    print (str(n)+':'+str(n[v]))
```

should be,

```
for v in n:
    print (str(v)+':'+str(n[v]) )
```

if variables made more sense would be something like,

```
for key in my_dict:
    print (str(key)+':'+str(my_dict[key]))  #my_dict[key] is value
```

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate this breakdown as it helped me realize what I was doing wrong. @s_vishnu

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate dictionary by key-value pair too. Check the manual. Here is an example of it.

```
for k, v in dict.items():
  print(k, v)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
i={'color':'red','gold':3}

def bP(n):
    inv='' 
    for key,value in n.items():
        print (str(key)+':'+str(value))
bP(i)
```

when you iterate dict then should use `items()` method

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to print `str(n)` which is your `dict`. Alternatively, you can `loop` through items of the dictionary as the following:

```
for k, v in n.items():
    print('{}:{}'.format(k, v))
```

While in your case, you can fix it by changing `str(n)`:

```
for v in n:
    print('{}:{}'.format(v, n[v]))
```